# Differential equation relating the height of the water to time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone help me with this problem?

I am given the following information[image: Task]

Assuming that the cistern has a regular cross-section A , I need to find the differential equation relating the height of the water to time and find it's control parameters using matlab.

So far i've tried the following equation $A\frac {dh}{dt} = -kh $
 where $k$ is the rate of change of volume.
However, i don't get the right results.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: since it's a cycle, the solution will be periodic. Good approximations of periodic effects are obtained with trigonometric functions, which are solutions of **second-order differential equations**.